# How to debug Shell Script

Tags: shell

```
export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:${PWD}:$PATH 
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/../config/ 
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true    
export ORDERER_CA=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem    
export ORDERER_ADDRESS=localhost:7050 
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG1=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt    
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG2=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
       CHANNEL_NAME="samplechannel" CHAINCODE_NAME="PropertyManagement"    CHAINCODE_VERSION="1"    CHAINCODE_PATH="../chaincode/PropertyManagement/build/install/PropertyManagement"    CHAINCODE_LANG="java" CHAINCODE_LABEL="PropertyManagement_1"
       
setEnvVarsForPeer0Org2() {    
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"    
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG2       
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp    
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:9051 
}
```

I am getting below error, any clue on this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heK4S.jpg)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to look into debugging - the error message clearly tells that the error is due to the script having CR at end of line (`\r` is CR). To rectify that, you can e. g.

- use `dos2unix chaincodelifecycle1.sh OUTFILE` or
- load the file in an editor which can save it with correct line endings or
- use `tr -d \\r <chaincodelifecycle1.sh >OUTFILE` etc.